# Applying 'Integrate' tool (data management) using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2

I try to integrate two features (shapes) with their ranks using ArcPy.

```
arcpy.Integrate_management()
```

I don't get a clue from the explanation/example in ArcGIS help. It's straight forward, however, to apply this tool from the graphical dialog.

I seek a working example having 2 shapes: a.shp (rank 1), b.shp (rank 2).

I'm using ArcGIS 10.2

Answer (score 1):

This is an example where shapefile 'a' will have rank 1 and shapefile 'b' will have rank 2, integrated with a tolerance of 100 meters:

```
import arcpy
a = r"C:\data\a.shp"
b = r"C:\data\b.shp"
arcpy.Integrate_management("a 1; b 2", "100 meters")
```

Trick: if you don't know the arcpy syntax of a tool, you can either

- put the tool with the desired parameters in Modelbuilder and export it to a Python script (Model menu > Export > To Python Script);
- run the tool (standalone) and export it as Python snippet from the geoprocessing results window (right-click the tool in the results window > Copy As Python Snippet).

Comment: I finally used a value table...  
vTab = arcpy.ValueTable(2)  
vTab.addRow("a.shp" + " 1")  
vTab.addRow("b.shp" + " 1")  
arcpy.Integrate_management(vTab,0.01)  
  
...but your approach seems to be a short cut to it.

Comment: @GISGe, you code won't work, this is what you meant arcpy.Integrate_management("{} 1; {} 2".format(a,b), "100 meters")